# How to annotate a list using @XmlElement?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I have the following annotation using `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement`:

```
@XmlElement         
public List<String> getKeywords() {
    return keywords;
}
```

Which produces the following XML when I marshall some example content:

```
<keywords>keyword1</keywords>
<keywords>keyword2</keywords>
```

I would like to get the following XML:

```
<keywords>
    <keyword>keyword1</keyword>
    <keyword>keyword2</keyword>
</keywords>
```

What kind of an annotation should I use?

I've tried

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name="keyword")
```

But then the whole content disappears and the result is:

```
<keywords/>
```

The same happens also if I only try to rename the element:

```
@XmlElement(name="keyword")
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is the updated full code for the class according to the first answers, but it is still not working (the result is an empty list `<keywords/>` when marshalled to XML):

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Content {

    private List<String> keywords;

    public Content() {}

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="keywords")
    @XmlElement(name="keyword")
    public List<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(List<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }  

}
```

I also tried the following with the same result:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Content {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="keywords")
    @XmlElement(name="keyword")
    private List<String> keywords;

    public Content() {}

    public List<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(List<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }  

}
```

However, the keywords are not empty as the following produces `<keywords>keyword1</keywords><keywords>keyword2</keywords>` instead of an empty list:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Content {

    private List<String> keywords;

    public Content() {}

    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(List<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }  

}
```

The code for marshalling is (JAX-RS):

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

@Path("process")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class ContentHandler {

    @POST
    public Response process(Content content) {

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Content.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(content, stringWriter);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            return Response.serverError().entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(stringWriter.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to leverage `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement`.

### Java Model

**Content**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Content {

    private List<String> keywords;

    public Content() {}

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="keyword")
    public List<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(List<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }  

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Content.class);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        strings.add("foo");
        strings.add("bar");

        Content content = new Content();
        content.setKeywords(strings);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(content, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<content>
    <keywords>
        <keyword>foo</keyword>
        <keyword>bar</keyword>
    </keywords>
</content>
```

### For More Information

Below are links to a couple articles from my blog that provide additional information:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html

Comment: Thanks, this works. There is a problem somewhere else in my code though, but that is a separate issue that I'll have to investigate.

Answer (score 22):

Use this form:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="keywords")
@XmlElement(name="keyword")
```

Please note that if `keywords` **is empty** then you will get `<keywords />`.

Sometimes you will need to add `@XmlRootElement` to your class (depends on the context) and the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.?)` annotation. I usually use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` and annotate my **fields** with `@XmlElement`.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work either. I updated my question with the full code for the class with these suggestions.

Comment: @user3429010 - Can you post the code where you populate the object model & marshal it to XML.

Comment: I updated my question with the code that I use for marshalling the object to XML. It is part of a RESTful service using Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer by - Blaise Doughan  is completely correct

Another simple way is , even if you don't write the  - @XmlElementWrapper

```
 private List<String> keywords;

 @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="keyword")
    public List<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }
```

You can use it this way - write the XmlAccessorType on Class level , then XML element name will be same as the class member name  - keywords

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Content {

    private List<String> keywords;

    public Content() {}


    public List<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(List<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }  

}
```