# Converting an XML to a JAXB Annotated Class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to convert the XML below into a JAXB annotated class but I'm having trouble thinking of a solution where an element repeats within an XML root.

```
   <addresses xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'>
       <address type='to' jid='hildjj@jabber.org/Work' />
       <address type='cc' jid='jer@jabber.org/Home' />
   </addresses>
```

I have this class that maps to the XML, I want an element 'address' with attributes 'type' and 'jid' to form within the XML Root Element 'addresses' for each item in the list that I pass in the constructor.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "addresses", namespace = "http://jabber.org/protocol/address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Addresses {

    @XmlElement
    private List<String> address;

    private Addresses() {
        // Private no-args default constructor for JAXB.
    }

    public Addresses(List<String> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

For example, if I pass a list ("User1", "User2", "User3") when instantiating the object, the resulting XML will look like:

```
   <addresses xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'>
       <address type='to' jid='User1' />
       <address type='to' jid='User2' />
       <address type='to' jid='User3' />
   </addresses>
```

Comment: Tried reading the solution posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307106/how-to-annotate-a-list-using-xmlelement). But it seems I cannot use the @XmlElementWrapper annotation because there is no way to set the attributes for the root element (e.g.the addresses' namespace)

Comment: The children of `<addresses>` are not simple string values. They are empty `<address>` elements with two attributes, so you need a class representing that object, i.e. an object with two fields: `type` and `jid`. Then replace `List<String>` with `List<Address>`.

Comment: Build a `xsd schema` first and then use maven plugin `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2` or `xjc` to build `JAXB` classes. Its cleaner to understand the elements hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by creating two classes Address and Addresses.
The Addresses root element will take a list of class 'Address' as the element input.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "addresses", namespace = "http://jabber.org/protocol/address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Addresses {

    @XmlElement
    private List<Address> address; //List of type address

    private Addresses() {
        // Private no-args default constructor for JAXB.
    }

    public Addresses(List<String> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

This is the address class with the attributes 'to' and 'jid'. It takes an input jid of type String in the constructor.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String to = 'to';

    @XmlAttribute
    private String jid;

    private Address() {
        // Private no-args default constructor for JAXB.
    }

    public Address(String jid) {
        this.jid = jid;
    }
}
```